# How to set more than one APP ID when using Google play game service

Tags: multiplayer, google-play-services

I want to use two different GAME ID in the same app.
Today the APP_ID is part the the Manifest.

Is there a way to set 2 GAME ID in the same app?

Thanks, 
Adrian.

Comment: Similar to this (unanswered) question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757450/googleplay-services-set-appid-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The published GamesClient class contains a getAppId() call, but not a corresponding setAppId. So I think you are stuck with what you can do in the manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/google_app_id" />
```

which means one, and only one, game per apk. This does, of course, mirror the setup instructions:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

You could, of course, have a different apk file for each game and call from one to the other at runtime to make it look like multiple games in one app from the user's perspective.